# Java TreeMap: Retrieving multiple values from a single key

Tags: java, key, treemap, treeset

I'm trying to retrieve multiple values from a single key in a TreeMap. The idea is that each key will link to multiple values and should be searchable. Right now the trouble I'm running into is that when I am only able to get one value back from the key.

The key is a String and the value is a custom object, called Song. Song contains multiple elements. The goal is to extract the lyrics, word by word, from each song and use each word as a key. The key then links to each Song (the value) that contains the key.

I've searched StackOverFlow and the web in general for tips, and I've seen a few, but nothing that directly addresses my stumbling block. One idea I saw was to change the value into some kind of array or list. I may try that tomorrow when my brain is refreshed.

Anyway, thanks in advance for any tips and advice. And yes, this is homework. No, I did not tag is because I was informed that the homework tag is no longer commonly in use.

Code:

```
public class SearchByLyricsWords {
   private static Song[] songs;

   private static TreeMap<String, Song> lyricsTreeMap = new TreeMap<String, Song>();

   private static TreeSet<String> wordsToIgnoreTree = new TreeSet<String>();
   private static File wordsToIgnoreInput = new File("ignore.txt");
   private static String wordsToIgnoreString;
   private static String[] wordsToIgnoreArray;

   private Song[] searchResults;  // holds the results of the search
   private ArrayList<Song> searchList = new ArrayList<Song>();  

public SearchByLyricsWords(SongCollection sc) throws FileNotFoundException {

  // Create a string out of the ignore.txt file
  Scanner scanInputFile = new Scanner(wordsToIgnoreInput);
  String ignoreToken = scanInputFile.next();
  ignoreToken.toLowerCase();
  wordsToIgnoreString = ignoreToken + " ";

  while (scanInputFile.hasNext()) {
     ignoreToken = scanInputFile.next();
     wordsToIgnoreString = wordsToIgnoreString + ignoreToken + " ";
  }

  // Split the string created from ignore.txt 
  wordsToIgnoreArray = wordsToIgnoreString.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

  // Fill a TreeSet from the wordsToIgnoreArray
  for (int i = 0; i < wordsToIgnoreArray.length; i++) {
     ignoreToken = wordsToIgnoreArray[i];
     wordsToIgnoreTree.add(ignoreToken);
  }

  // Fill TreeMap with lyrics words as the key, Song objects as the value
  songs = sc.getAllSongs();

  for (int j = 0; j < songs.length; j++) {
     Song currentSong = songs[j];
     String lyrics = currentSong.getLyrics();         
     TreeSet<String> lyricsFound = new TreeSet<String>();

     String lyricsToken;
     String[] songLyricsArray;
     songLyricsArray = lyrics.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

     for (int k = 0; k < songLyricsArray.length; k++) {
        lyricsToken = songLyricsArray[k];

        if (lyricsToken.length() <= 1) {
           continue;
        }

        lyricsFound.add(lyricsToken);
     }

     lyricsFound.removeAll(wordsToIgnoreTree);

     Iterator<String> iterator = lyricsFound.iterator();

     while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        String currentWord = (String)iterator.next();
        lyricsTreeMap.put(currentWord, currentSong);
     }

     //System.out.println(lyricsTreeMap); // testing only
  }
}


public Song[] search(String lyricsWords) {

  lyricsWords = lyricsWords.toLowerCase();
  TreeSet<String> searchTree = new TreeSet<String>();
  String searchToken;
  String[] lyricsWordsSearch = lyricsWords.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");

  for (int l = 0; l < lyricsWordsSearch.length; l++) {
     searchToken = lyricsWordsSearch[l];

     if (searchToken.length() <= 1) {
        continue;            
     }
     searchTree.add(searchToken);
  }
  searchTree.removeAll(wordsToIgnoreTree);

  Iterator<String> searchIterator = searchTree.iterator();

  while(searchIterator.hasNext()) {
     String currentSearchWord = (String)searchIterator.next();
     Collection<Song> lyricsTreeCollection = lyricsTreeMap.values();

     while (lyricsTreeMap.containsKey(currentSearchWord) == true) {

        Iterator collectionIterator = lyricsTreeCollection.iterator();

        while(collectionIterator.hasNext() && collectionIterator.next() == currentSearchWord) {

           Song searchSong = lyricsTreeMap.get(currentSearchWord);
           searchList.add(searchSong);          
        }
     }           
  }
  searchResults = searchList.toArray(new Song[searchList.size()]);

  Arrays.sort(searchResults);

  return searchResults;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`TreeMap` only keeps one value per key, [as with all `Map` implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.

Your alternatives include

- use a `TreeMap<String, List<Song>>` instead, and manually deal with the `List` values and keeping them updated
- use [e.g. a `TreeMultimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) from Guava, which (more or less) operates like a `TreeMap<K, TreeSet<V>>`, except a lot better.  (Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: Darn. Okay, my misunderstanding. I knew that the keys had to be unique but I didn't understand that they would only map to one value. Thanks.

Comment: I think inner structure should be `Set` rather then `List` for storing the values which will automatically omit redundant values for the key.

Comment: This makes sense in context of the assignment. I was under the impression that in a TreeMap the value operated as a set. I am still (struggling) to learn this stuff, as you can tell. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Whether you want to use a `Set` or a `List` really, really depends on the use case, which I don't think we have enough details on.  That's for the OP to decide.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoule set your structure as

```
Map<String, Set<Song>>
```

Here `Set` is used as inner Collection class rather then `List`. Because it will automatically omit the redundent value for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this format to initialize the map and set:

```
Map<String, TreeSet<Song>>=new Map<String,treeSet<Song>>();
```

Than you will need a multiple for loops to loop first thru the song set and than get the Map keys to insert into your Map.
Like so:

```
    for(Song temp:songs){
       for(String word:temp.getLyrics().toLowerCase().split("[^a-zA-Z]+"){
             if(lyricsTreeMap.containsKey(word)){
                  lyricsTreeMap.get(word).add(temp);
    }
```